# How can I configure auto-capitalization behavior in Flutter's text entry fields?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield, capitalization

I'm experimenting with Flutter development on Windows.  I have a simple test app with an InputField.  I would like the first keyboard entry to be a capital letter but can't see a way of achieving that (e.g. launching the keyboard with shift pressed) that at the moment.  Any ideas?

Code (a bit simplified) is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData.dark(),
      home: new MainScreen()
  ));
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            leading: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.menu),
                tooltip: 'Navigation menu',
                onPressed: null,
            ),
            title: new Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: new NewTest(),
    );
  }
}

/// Widget
class NewTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewTestInputState createState() => new _NewTestInputState();
}
/// State
class _NewTestInputState extends State<NewTest> {
  InputValue _currentInput;

  void _handleInputChange(InputValue input) {
    if (input != _currentInput){
      setState(() {
        _currentInput = input;
      });
    }
  }

  void _handleInputSubmitted(InputValue input) {
    setState(() {
      _currentInput = const InputValue();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InputField _widget = new InputField(
        value: _currentInput,
        hintText: 'Enter text',
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        autofocus: true,
        onChanged: _handleInputChange,
        onSubmitted: _handleInputSubmitted,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    );
    Container _container = new Container(
        child: _widget,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border: new Border.all(
                color: Colors.green[300],
                width: 2.0,
            ),
        ),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    );
    return _container;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example Android or iOS application which has this behavior?

Or an example iOS or Android API we should expose via Flutter's default Keyboard wrapper?

If so we're happy to do so!  And welcome a feature request at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

Comment: Sure - www.swipesapp.com is a todo site with an IOS app that supports this when you add a new task.

Comment: Or how about the standard Notes app on the iPhone?  Start a new note and the keyboard starts with shift pressed, as I would like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The starting-lowercase was a bug in our iOS implementation of Flutter's keyboard wrapper, which has since been fixed as of today!

I filed a bug for making this configurable (so you can disable the autocapitalize sentences behavior) here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9363

Please don't hesitate to reach out if this does not resolve your issue.

Answer (score 83):

Flutter has a **textCapitalization** property for textfields. Set this property to **TextCapitalization.sentences** or any of the available values eg **.characters or .words** Like so:

```
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
   **textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,**
   style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 30.0,
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common issue is that for some reason:

`keyboardType: TextInputType.name` does not capitalize the first letter, although you would think a "name" would be capitalized.

So a typical user would then add:

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
```

But that doesn't work unless you REMOVE `keyboardType: TextInputType.name` and then it works as expected. There are other combinations of this frustrating behavior.

Remove the keyboard type, but leave the textCapitalization: `TextCapitalization.words`

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: My answer elaborates on the conflict that exists between having both keyboardType.name and textCapitalization.words...it seems to short circuit things.  If you correctly only have TextCapitalization.words and it's not capitalizing, that would be a new bug for Flutter to be made aware of.

Comment: To make the keyboard also caps all the time you need to set keyboardType: `TextInputType.text` and `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters` to the TextField.